# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{n^{1.001}}}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to evalulate

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{n^{1.001}}}{n!}$$

I thought that the limit is $0$ as same as $\dfrac{2^{n}}{n!}$, but apparently it's $
\infty$ and I just can't find the way to prove it.

Please, help

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**  Note that $n!\le n^n$, and take the logarithm of our expression.  This logarithm is $\ge (\ln 2)n^{1.001} -n\ln n$.

Comment: It's for students who are not familiar with $ln$.. any other solution?

Comment: If they know the properties of some version of logarithm, the same argument can be used. I do not have a suggestion if they are not.

Comment: @Eyalbason How did you reach limits without touching logarithms?

Comment: And how a student is doing calculus and limits without knowing the basic, at least, of logarithms? Not ofence intended *at all*, but you may want to fix this before advancing any more.

Comment: @UserX: How do you even define logarithms rigorously without already having a limit concept?

Comment: @HenningMakholm that can be said to almost any non-rational function. They were defined as the inverse of exponentials to me.

Comment: @UserX: And how do you define exponentials (with not-necessarily-rational exponents) without already having a limit concept?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Something along the lines; $f(x)\colon =a^x$ or $x\stackrel{f}{\mapsto} a^x$ along with some important values, a<1 or a>1, properties and graphs. I don't understand your objection. Do you require 7 year olds to learn fields because you hate temporary definitons/work arounds too?

Comment: @UserX: $f(x) = a^x$ doesn't define anything -- it assumes that you alreay know what $a^x$ means. How do you give any meaning to $a^x$ for $x\notin\mathbb Q$ without having a concept of limit?

Comment: What I learnt(and what I suppose other people learn in HS over the globe) is a vague definition of a limit, along the lines; "arbitrarily close to". As I said it's a temporary work-around.

Comment: @UserX, I don't think (and I *hope*) it wasn't that vague at college/university level. While in high school that may suffice, but not at more advanced level.

Comment: @UserX: So you now acknowledge that a concept of limits (vague or not) is necessary in order to define exponentials and logarithms. Then I don't understand your initial objection. It is quite possible to speak of limits without knowing logarithms, but not the other way around.

Comment: @HenningMakholm my objection is that you CAN speak of logarithms as long as you see them as a calculation tool without requiring deeper understanding.

Comment: OK, the students WILL learn logarithms next week (which will make the proof for this limit so much easier) but until then they need to evaluate that series anyway.

Comment: @UserX: Then you still need to explain how you propose to introduce this "calculation tool" without having a concept of limits. And in particular you need to explain why on earth you think knowing logarithms are necessary for talking about limits.

Comment: Certainly for *computing* some limits properties of the logarithm are useful.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take: for $n$ big enough, $2^{n^\varepsilon}>n$ (this is a consequence of the fact that $(\log n)/n^{\varepsilon}\to0$ for any $\varepsilon>0$). Then
$$
\frac{2^{n^{1+\varepsilon}}}{n!}=\frac{2^{n\cdot n^{\varepsilon}}}{n!}
=\frac{(2^{n^\varepsilon})^n}{n!}=\frac{2^{n^\varepsilon}}n\frac{2^{n^\varepsilon}}{n-1}\cdots\frac{2^{n^\varepsilon}}2\frac{2^{n^\varepsilon}}1>2^{n^\varepsilon}\to\infty.
$$
Thus,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{n^{1+\varepsilon}}}{n!}=\infty
$$
for all $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: I think the exponent of that $\;n\;$ there is $\;1.001\;$ , *not* $\;1001\;$ .

Comment: Thanks. The same idea still applies, so I have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Although properties and computations of logarithms (including exponents) are well developed in precalculus, more advanced techniques with logs and exponents such as derivatives, integrals, and yes limits too with natural logarithms do not come until much later in a first course in calculus with analytic geometry. Limits and simple derivatives are examined early in such a course which may explain Eyalbason's deficit in limits of logarithmic functions. So please try to exercise patience. We were all there at one time.